# Updating datetime field from a date field throws error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to update a datetime field on a table (MyTable1) from a date field on another table (MyTable2).

- DateTime value in datetime field in MyTable1 is stored following
  below format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff
- Date value in date field in MyTable2 is stored following below format
  yyyy-mm-dd

So taking into account this, I perform below 2 attempts without success.
What am I doing wrong?

**ATTEMPT #1**:

```
UPDATE tblToUpdate
   SET tblToUpdate.DateTimeField = fromTbl.DateField
  FROM MyTable1 tblToUpdate INNER JOIN MyTable2 fromTbl on tblToUpdate.Id = fromTbl.Id
```

This produces below error:

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range value

**ATTEMPT #2**:

```
UPDATE tblToUpdate
   SET tblToUpdate.DateTimeField = (case when fromTbl.DateField is NULL 
                                           then NULL 
                                           else format(fromTbl.DateField, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff') end)
  FROM MyTable1 tblToUpdate INNER JOIN MyTable2 fromTbl on tblToUpdate.Id = fromTbl.Id
```

This produces below error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

Comment: Date datatypes don't have a format

Comment: The error is VERY clear. One of those columns is string and one is date/datetime - contrary to your description. So - which one is it?

Comment: And i'll note that the error might also be thrown by the attempt to join on dissimilar datatypes for Id. Show the DDL for the tables. A trigger might also be the source of the problem - this would be apparent if you included all of the error details.

Comment: @SMor there are no string columns in MyTable1 and MyTable2. In MyTable1 column is of type DateTime and in MyTable2 column is of type Date.

Comment: What is you smallest `date` value? Data type DATE has a range of accepted values from 01-01-0001 through 12-31-9999, data type DATETIME has a range of accepted values from 01-01-1753 through 12-31-9999.

Comment: @HoneyBadger How can i know the range of these columns?

Comment: @user1624552, you can just `SELECT MIN(DateField) FROM yourTable`. If the result is < 01-01-1753 that's probably the issue.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Oh my God! Yes, you are right, there was a result < 01-01-1753. This was the culprit.Thx!!!!

Comment: @user1624552 its a common trap ;) You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

`yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.nnn` isn't an ambiguous format with the `datetime` datatype. The only 2 are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnn`. I also suggest against `FORMAT`, as it's an awfully show function. If you must supply a non-ambiguous `varchar` value, use `CONVERT` and a [style code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles):

```
CONVERT(varchar(23),fromTbl.DateField,126)
```

This will supply a `varchar` value in the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnn`. For example, with `GETDATE()` I get the value `'2019-11-27T12:32:27.763'` right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the values to the same as you can only substitute the new date with the old date, if they are the same timeformat. Try something like this.

```
UPDATE tblToUpdate
   SET tblToUpdate.DateTimeField = CONVERT(datetime,fromTbl.DateField)
  FROM MyTable1 tblToUpdate INNER JOIN MyTable2 fromTbl on tblToUpdate.Id = fromTbl.Id
```